# How to update mirrored variable in tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu

I am building a model in tensorflow version 2.0 (upgrading is not an option due to compatibility with my version of cuda, which I do not have permission to change). I am using `tf.strategy.MirroredStrategy()` to train my model on 2 GPUs. However, I am trying to instantiate a custom dense layer whose weights are the transpose of the weights of a different dense layer. My code involves this line to build the custom layer:

```py
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

class DenseTied(Layer):
    # Really long class, full code can be found at link below

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel = K.transpose(self.tied_to.kernel)
```

I am then using this in a model as follows:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense

def build_model(input_shape):
    model_input = Input(shape=input_shape)
    dense1 = Dense(6144, activation='relu')
    dense_tied1 = DenseTied(49152, tied_to=dense1)

    x = dense1(model_input)
    model_output = dense_tied1(x)

    model = Model(model_input, model_output)

    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

    return model
```

When trying to build this model I get an error: `AttributeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute '_distribute_strategy'`.
I have been tracking this down for a while now and I pinpointed that the issue is in the line

```py
self.kernel = K.transpose(self.tied_to.kernel)
```

It seems that `self.tied_to.kernel` is of type `<class 'tensorflow.python.distribute.values.MirroredVariable'>` but after calling `K.transpose()` on it the resulting output is of type `<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>`. I tried following the instructions [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/StrategyExtended) but it did not work. I get `AttributeError: 'MirroredStrategy' object has no attribute 'run'` when in the docs it does. So I think maybe my version of Tensorflow is too old for that method.

How can I update a mirrored variable in Tensorflow 2.0?

Also if you want to see the full custom layer code, I am trying to implement the dense tied layer described [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/build-the-right-autoencoder-tune-and-optimize-using-pca-principles-part-ii-24b9cca69bd6).

Answer (score 3):

As of now, the documentation is for tensorflow 2.3. If you are using 2.0 it should be
`strategy.experimental_run_v2` instead of `strategy.run`.